# Clearing data in a cloned fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

The fieldset in now cloning without retaining data from the previous fieldset as I intended. Thank you RobG and ATOzTOA for all your help.

The only problem I'm having now is the calendar is nonfunctional in the cloned fieldsets.

I have looked through several threads where people have had the same problem as me and I apologize for creating another thread on the subject.

Script for calendar dropdown.

```
<!-- calendar dropdown -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#datepicker").datepicker();      
});    
</script>
```

Script to clone the fieldset.

```
<!-- clone fieldset -->          
<script>
var _counter = 0;
function Add() {
_counter++;
var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
oClone.id += (_counter + "");
document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
var inputs = oClone.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; 
i<iLen; i++) {
inputs[i].value = '';
}
}
</script>
```

Fieldset to be cloned.

```
<div id="placeholder">
<!-- template -->
<div id="template">
<!-- event fieldset -->
<fieldset>           
  <label class="field-first" required>Event: &#42;<input type="text" name="event" value="" /></label>
  <label class="field-first" required>Date: &#42;<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="" /></label>
  <label class="field-first" required>Net Request Amount: &#42;<input type="text" name="request" value="" /></label>

  <div class="description"><p>Please type a <strong><em>DETAILED</em></strong> description of the item/event/activity:<br /></p></div>

  <textarea name="describe" cols="60" rows="10" required></textarea>
<!-- event fieldset -->
</fieldset>
<!-- template -->      
</div>
<!-- placeholder -->
</div> 
<!-- buttons -->
<button class="right-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
<button class="left-button" "btn" type="button" name="Submit"  onclick="Add();">Add New Event</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are adding content to the labels. You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get the labels from the clone, then set their innerHTML to '' (empty string) to remove any child nodes (or loop over the child nodes and remove them, but setting the innerHTML property is simpler). While looping over the labels, you can modify any other properties that might need it.

If you just want to clear the value of the input elements, same strategy only use `getElementsByTagName('input')` and set their `value` property to `` (empty string).

Note that you have three input elements with a name of "first_name". It doesn't seem like a good idea to do that when none of them seems to be a first name. Use a name that represents the data they hold or the purpose to which it will be put. It also doesn't seem to be necessary to have one with an ID of "datepicker". Either remove the ID, or if you need it (unlikley), modify the value so it's unique to each cloned fragment.

#### Edit

To use `getElementsByTagName` to set the input values to "":

```
var inputs = oClone.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to clear the value of the elements inside the fieldset. I didn't notice the elements with duplicate names, I must of forgot to rename them after pasting them. I have changed their names to correspond with the data. The date picker ID is to enable a dropdown calendar. I have tried to add the code you suggested, but the data isn't clearing. The updated code is posted above.

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) (like an array it has a length that is the number of members and you can access them by index from 0). You will need to iterate over the list and set each member's value to "" (e.g. use a for loop).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to traverse through each element in the frameset and set text() to "".

```
var div = document.getElementById('template'):
var labels = div.getElementsByTagName('label');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
  code = labels[i].innerHTML;
    // As there is a input element inside the label, we have to modify the HTML code
    codeArray = code.split('&lt');
    codeArray[0] = '';
    code = codeArray.join('&lt;');
    labels[i] = code;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Would I do that in the HTML or javascript?

Comment: Javascript or easier in jquery.

Comment: I tried adding the code you have suggested and done some experimenting, but I'm unable to clear the content in the labels. I am still trying and appreciate everyone's help.